# Создание конструктора 2D RPG

Tags: c#

Здравствуй, ХэшКод. Скажите, я захотел сделать свой конструктор 2D RPG (простенький), типа Mirage Engine, так вот на чем лучше сделать? XNA или же Windows Forms? Потому что сам Mirage Engine был написан на Standart EXE VB 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XNA - это хороший разумный выбор для написания 2D-игры особенно с целью обучения. В то время как Windows Forms - это каркас для разработки приложений общего назначения. Вы можете найти [здесь](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/) полезные примеры для обучения. Также есть некоторый смысл в том, чтобы порыться на хостингах исходников, и посмотреть на то, что находится там, типа [подобного](http://code.google.com/p/netgore/).